# XSLT-UNBPRFX with local function

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to replace specified list of nodes in an document with XSLT api with local function but I see following exception thru xquery/MarkLogic.

```
[XSLT] XSLT-UNBPRFX: (err:XTSE0280) Prefix local has no namespace binding
Stack Trace

At line 5 column 0:
In xdmp:xslt-eval(<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:co...</xsl:stylesheet>, <PersonalInfo><ContactInfo><firstName>Jon</firstName><lastName>Smith</lastName...</PersonalInfo>)
3. declare function local:changecontent($type) as xs:string
4. {
5. switch($type)
6. case "ssn" return "111-11-1111"
7. case "Country" return "United State"
At line 29 column 7:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;declare function loc...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>15163595336534263915</database><isolation>different-tr...</options>)
$stylesheet := <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:co...</xsl:stylesheet>
27. </xsl:stylesheet>
28. 
29. return xdmp:xslt-eval($stylesheet, document{ <PersonalInfo>
30. <ContactInfo>
31. <firstName>Jon</firstName>
In /MarkLogic/appservices/qconsole/qconsole-amped.xqy on line 200
In amped-qconsole:qconsole-eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;declare function loc...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>15163595336534263915</database><isolation>different-tr...</options>)
$xquery := "xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;declare function loc..."
$vars := ()
$options := <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>15163595336534263915</database><isolation>different-tr...</options>
```

Here is the source code :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:changecontent($type) as xs:string
{
switch($type)
  case "ssn" return "111-11-1111"
  case "Country" return "United State"
  default return "Dummy"
};

let $stylesheet  := <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ssn|Country">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="local:changecontent(local-name(.))"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

return xdmp:xslt-eval($stylesheet, document{ <PersonalInfo>
  <ContactInfo>
    <firstName>Jon</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <ssn>123-33-2222</ssn>
    <addr>
       <addr1>123 Mocking Bird Lane</addr1>
       <city>Queens</city>
       <state>NY</state>
     </addr>
   </ContactInfo>
  </PersonalInfo>
  }/element())
```

Comment: In the `xsl:stylesheet` element, you need to add a namespace declaration for the prefix 'local', you used it in your stylesheet (local:changecontent...).

Answer (score 1):

The error is about a non-declared namespace. But adding the local namespace decl won't help unfortunately. It won't be able to find the function. The local functions are not passed through to the context of xslt-eval. You have two options:

1. Convert the function to an xsl:function
2. Push the XQuery function into a library, and import that

You can import XQuery library modules like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... extension-element-prefixes="xdmp"
  xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json">

  <xdmp:import-module namespace="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" href="/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy"/>

  ..
  <xsl:sequence select="json:transform-to-json(.)"/>
  ..
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTH!

Comment: I tried with adding to module library, but still i get [XSLT] XSLT-UNBPRFX: (err:XTSE0280) Prefix disp has no namespace binding

Comment: import module namespace disp = "http://marklogic.com/MLU/personal-data/display" at "modules/display-lib.xqy"; this was added

Comment: the changecontent function is inside display-lib.xqy

Comment: You need to import the XQuery library into the XSLT, as I was showing in my code sample above with the built-in JSON library. Importing it into XQuery module alone is not enough. The XSLT is executed against a different context. Note that you need to declare the namespace prefix in the XSLT as well, to be able to reference your disp functions.

Answer (score 0):

`XSLT-UNBPRFX` means you have an undefined namespace prefix. XSLT does not define `local` for you. If you need the default definition of `local` you can get it with a simple XQuery expression:

```
namespace-uri(<local:x/>)
```

This yields:

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/xquery-local-functions
```